# c++ template - type/value mismatch - Instantiate base class template with a type dependent on derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

The following code fails to compile with type/value mismatch error, however I know a type is being supplied. What am I missing ?

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct base {};

template<typename B>
struct derived : base< derived<B>::type, B >
{
  using type = int;
}

int main()
{
  derived<char> d;
}

error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter
list for 'template<class A, class B> struct base'
struct derived : base< derived<B>::type, B >

note: expected a type, got 'derived<B>::type'
```

Why is `derived<B>::type` not a valid type ?

Moreover tried the following :

```
template<typename B>
struct derived : base< typename derived<B>::type, B >
{
  using type = int;
}
```

And got the following error :

```
no type name 'type' in 'struct derived<char>'
```

Why does compiler fail to detect type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing two different issues at play here.  The first is that `derived<B>::type` is a dependent type name, so you have to use the `typename` keyword to inform the compiler that it is a type and not an object:

```
template<typename B>
struct derived : base< typename derived<B>::type, B >
{
  using type = int;
}
```

That's not enough in this case though, since `derived<B>` isn't defined yet, so `derived<B>::type` doesn't exist yet.

For simple cases, you could just hard-code the type both places:

```
template<typename B>
struct derived : base< int, B >
{
  using type = int;
}
```

For more complex cases, or if you want to avoid accidentally changing the template parameter and the using directive to be different in the future, you could pull `type` out into some other trait so that it's accessible before `derived` is defined:

```
template <typename B>
struct my_trait
{
    using type = int;
};

template <typename B>
struct derived : base < typename my_trait<B>::type, B >
{
    using type = typename my_trait<B>::type;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbdaea2e8e268868)

Answer (score 2):

> **Why does compiler fail to detect type ?**

From [class#mem-6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem-6)

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type ([basic.types])
>   (or complete type) at the closing **`}`** of the class-specifier.

Thus, `struct derived` is of incomplete type and declaring `derived<B>::type` as a template parameter would be ill-formed.